# Combining var and Dynamic statements

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Heres a fun problem I have.

I have a function that returns a var of items;

```
  var Items = new { sumList = SumList, ratesList = List, sum = List.Sum() };
        return Items;
```

From a function that is dynamic:

```
    public override dynamic GetRates()
```

and I return it to a function I else where and try to apply it to my code:

```
     dynamic res = cl.mainC.GetRates();
     List<double> MashkantaSumList = res.sumList;
```

Now when I try to apply it, it says the object doesnt exist. But if I look in the debugger the items are happily there as a generic list or what not.

How do I resolve this?

EDIT:

as per request I'll post the full code:

```
 //virtual
   public virtual dynamic TotalMashkanta(int i, double sum, double ribit, string[] discount)
    {
        return 0;
    }

//override
public override dynamic TotalMashkanta(int i, double sum, double ribit, string[] discount)
    {
        double SumTemp = sum;
        double monthlyRibit = ribit / 12;
        Double permPayPerMont = Financial.Pmt(monthlyRibit, i, sum, 0, DueDate.EndOfPeriod);
        List<double> MashkantaList = new List<double>();
        List<double> MashkantaSumList = new List<double>();
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            MashkantaList.Add(Mashkanta(j, sum, ribit, permPayPerMont) * (1 - CalcDiscount((j / 12) + 1, discount)));
            SumTemp = getSum(j, sum, ribit, permPayPerMont * -1); ;
            MashkantaSumList.Add(SumTemp);
        }
        var K_Mashkanta = new { sumList = MashkantaSumList, ratesList = MashkantaList, sum = MashkantaList.Sum() };
        return K_Mashkanta;
    }


  //Function that calls the results


  public void GetSilukinTable(string Path, string ClientID, DAL.Client client, string partner_checked,  string insurance_Amount, string Premiya_Structure_Mashkanta, string Premiya_Life_Mashkanta, string Discount_Life_Mashkanta, string Loan_Period,string Loan_EndDate, string Bank, string Loan_Interest, string Loan_Amount, string Discount_Loan, string AgentNotes, string ManID)
    {

        BL.CalculateLogic.Companies t = BL.CalculateLogic.Companies.כלל;
        if(ManID == "211") t = BL.CalculateLogic.Companies.הפניקס;
        if(ManID == "207") t = BL.CalculateLogic.Companies.הראל;
        if(ManID == "206") t = BL.CalculateLogic.Companies.מנורה;
        if(ManID == "208") t = BL.CalculateLogic.Companies.הכשרה;
        BL.CalculateLogic cl = new BL.CalculateLogic(client, t);
        DateTime LoanEnd = DateTime.Now;
        int months = 0;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Loan_EndDate, out LoanEnd))
            months = BL.Calculating_Companies.Company.GetMonthsBetween(DateTime.Now, LoanEnd);
        else
            months = Int32.Parse(Loan_Period) * 12;
        string[] Discount = Discount_Loan.Split('-');

        dynamic res = cl.mainC.TotalMashkanta(months, Double.Parse(Loan_Amount), Double.Parse(Loan_Interest.Trim('%')), Discount);
        var MashkantaSumList = res.sumList;
        List<double> MashkantaList = res.ratesList;
        List<double> MashkantaSumListPartner = new List<double>();
        List<double> MashkantaListPartner = new List<double>();
        List<double> MashkantaListSum = res.ratesList;

    }
```

Comment: Your coding style does not really match C# conventions.

Comment: So murder me, what can I say

Comment: Actually there was a reason I didnt want to post the full code cause its so god damn confusing

Comment: Make it unconfusing... That is the real point. It will make your life easier and you can analyze it yourself.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using dynamic? I don't see a valid reason to use it...

Comment: Your code is fine. I just checked a stripped version and there is no issue with the `dynamic`.

Comment: my Eyes!!!!!! Enums with Hebrew values??? Use some resource files for that.. btw anonymous objects are internal - so If your method returns an anonymous object and is located in a different dll, that’s probably your problem..

Comment: Amir Popovich here is right. Luckily there is honestly no reason for me to use dynamic, other than pure experimantion.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is happy about it because `dynamic` is compiled and checked at run time. Whatever the problem is, the types don't match. It evaluates this at run time, so you won't see issues at compile time. (Advice: use `dynamic` only when you really must! Else you will have this kind of problems all the time!)

---

I tried your code using this and it works fine:

```
static dynamic GetRates()
{
    List<double> SumList = new List<double>();
    List<double> List = new List<double>();
    var Items = new { sumList = SumList, ratesList = List, sum = List.Sum() };
    return Items;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic res = GetRates();
    List<double> MashkantaSumList = res.sumList;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what is `SumList`. Maybe it is list of some sums.

Comment: @misha130: Still, the same rule applies. What is the data type of `sumList`?

Comment: List<double> SumList = new List<double>();